# Block a user from accessing all sharepoint online sites, while keeping his account active

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365

I got a requirement from one of our customers is that they want to prevent a user from accessing all the SharePoint online site collections inside their office 365 tenant, while keep the user account active.

So I am not sure if SharePoint online support such an operation?

Keeping in mind that we have many sites which were granted permission to the users through the "Everyone except external", so this user is granted access to some site indirectly through this group.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint online don't support such an operation.

similar issue post for your reference:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/blocking-users-from-spo/m-p/7404

Comment: is the link saying that removing the user's SharePoint online license will prevent the user from accessing the SharePoint sites?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following any of the below options:

1. Use Azure Active Directory Conditional Access. By using it, you can block this specific user from accessing specific Microsoft 365 service, i.e. SharePoint.
2. You can remove the SharePoint user license, but to let this work, you have to open a case with Microsoft to enable your SharePoint Online tenant to respect the SharePoint license. However, please note that this configuration will be respected for all your tenant users. In other words, once this is enabled, all your tenant users, who don't have SharePoint license, won't be able to access SharePoint.